# Raspberry pi 3 model b+ Plex client

Tags: media

I've recently bought a new Raspberry Pi which was for me to do some stuff on (Pihole, docker... things etc.)

The Roku in our bedroom died the day after it arrived, and I don't want to replace it since I'm waiting to see whether NVidia are announcing a new Shield as people are expecting. I decided to just throw Rasplex on the pi and use that for a few months.

Unfortunately it hasn't been updated for 2 years and apparently people are struggling with it booting, with it claiming undervoltage even when the power is fine. I had this same issue.

I tried a community fork which was even worse, does anyone know of a decent RPi plex client? I'd rather not go with Kodi + the plugin

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it the RPi or the Roku which is having trouble booting?
2. If it is the Roku, this is the wrong place.
3. However, if it is the RPi, try doing a clean re-installation. Follow the steps [here](http://www.rasplex.com/get-started/rasplex-installers.html) You can use your current SD card and it should work fine.
   This re-installation should give you the most recent version, and remove any problems you may have. If you encounter any problems, please leave a comment below with @Ntechh.

Comment: The Roku is dead as a doornail, I'm trying to replace it in the interim with the Pi.

It boots fine with raspian or any other OS, but rasplex, which apparently is a common issue.

I have repeatedly installed all sorts of things, what I would like is a recommendation for a Plex client

Comment: @GordonBennet, I don't believe there's any other Plex clients, as it is not opensource.